# why aren't the instruction pointers saved in little endian?

Tags: computer-architecture

I'm fairly new to architecture and I kinda get little endian wrong sometimes. So In this snippet I overflowed the sub-routine's stack frame just to affect the SAVED RBP and when I looked at the SAVED RETURN ADDRESS it didn't seem like it was written in little endian format. My confusion arose after I saw that the payload was in little endian (seeing how that last 4 characters were stored) but the saved return address wasn't, Can someone explain why this happened?

P.S. running a V.M. on an x86_64 bit intel processor[image: snippet of GDB debugger at the time]

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from GDB trying to group the RBP dump into 32-bit chunks, even though technically GDB wouldn't have enough information on how they were originally pushed into the stack. A 64-bit value on the stack is thus displayed as two 32-bit chunks, and GDB's way of displaying each chunk involves its own endian swap.

As a reminder, on x86 and x86-64, the stack is consumed backwards, i.e. the stack pointer is initialized to a higher address; each push operation decreases the stack pointer by the width of data pushed.

I guess this is what I'm reading. Hopefully this clarifies for you.

```
// the return address after calling authorize
0xffffe138  0x0000555555555241 (main + 0x14) 

// the address that follows immediately after the last "ret" of the function main 
0xffffe140  0x0000555555555270 (main + 0x61)
```

Comment: hmm so I extended the initial payload with an address that i wrote that in little endian too. After i did that, the representation was the same as the previous return address(not surprising), but it was successfully loaded into the RIP and the instruction that i made it point too was executed.

Comment: @MichaelG This question may have answers for your remaining puzzles. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44801/smashing-the-stack-if-it-grows-upwards

Comment: yes, you're right. When I used x/10xb to display the stack byte by byte, it was displayed in little endian. Seems like gdb was having trouble when trying to dump as 32 bit chunks. Thanks

Comment: It is not a trouble, defect, or shortcoming in GDB. It is inherent in little-endian machines that, if one were to perform endian-swap operation correctly (on memory data), one must first find out the true width of the data. Without knowing the true width, there is no correct way to perform an endian-swap.

Comment: that's interesting....is that why using x/10xb displays 64bit chunks, which ruins the way the initial payload is displayed (it is displayed in big endian when i use x/10xb). Since the initial payload was grouped into 32bits earlier.